# Spec Failing undefined method `parameterize'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a custom validation on a model and I'm getting undefined method which makes no sense.

Here's the code

```
  validate :unique_seo_url_from_title

 def unique_seo_url_from_title
    url = "#{title.parameterize}-#{region.parameterize}-#{country}"
    errors.add(:title, "already in use") if SeoMapping.find_by_seo_url(url)
  end
```

Strange thing is if I output the url ie raise url it prints it perfectly so its working.

Hope someone can advise!

Comment: Are both `title` and `region` Strings? What is full error message you get (usually it says *undefined method ... for ...*). Where do you put `raise url` which you say is working?

Comment: Yes for both. Error is: undefined method `parameterize' for nil:NilClass and If I raise between url and the errors.add.

Comment: Sorry it is still unclear on which object parameterize is called when it is failing. You'd better debug into it. `find_by_seo_url` is Rails dynamic finder or your own method?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't pass parameters to the function, it seems that title, region and country are attributes of model for which validation is used. So use self for the object

validate :unique_seo_url_from_title

```
 def unique_seo_url_from_title
    url = "#{self.title.parameterize}-#{self.region.parameterize}-#{self.country}"
    errors.add(:title, "already in use") if SeoMapping.find_by_seo_url(url)
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: I already tried self but still the same error message. I should have said in thread.

Comment: Can you give whole model. also what is the title, region and country since it is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
undefined method `parameterize' for nil:NilClass
```

The message means exactly what it says. You have an object which is `nil`, and you call `parameterize` on it -- which fails because that method is defined on `String`, not `NilClass`.

Check that the values for `title` and `region` are present. If not, there's your problem.